# Do most aircraft require a nose-up attitude for level flight?

Tags: aerodynamics

I recently saw a picture of a HUD on a commercial plane, and I noticed the nose was level to the horizon but the flight path indicator is almost always under the horizon line no matter the speed, does this mean most commercial jets require a slight nose-up attitude to fly at a level and consistent altitude?
https://c8.alamy.com/comp/PJJCKW/aircraft-heads-up-display-hud-on-a-modern-boeing-787-airliner-PJJCKW.jpg
Similar to that